# How to publish a android library with java module?

Tags: java, android, gradle, aar, jcenter

My Project

- moduleA

- moduleAPT

- moduleJ

Above is my project structure. The moduleA is a shared library module, and moduleJ is a java module that contains some annotation classes, and moduleAPT is an annotation processing tool module that handles moduleJ's annotation classes.
Both moduleA and moduleAPT have a dependence line in their build.gradle file like this:

```
api project(':moduleJ')
```

Now i want to publish the moduleA to jcenter. The problem is the generated aar file do not contains source files in moduleJ.
How to merge moduleJ's classes to moduleA's aar file when compiling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library to package aar
[fat-aar-android](https://github.com/kezong/fat-aar-android)

I'm using it, it can merge multiple module